# How do we force Resource(controller) level transaction in Dropwizard with jdbi?

Tags: java, transactions, dao, dropwizard, jdbi

In spring, we have `@Transactional` annotation which can be specified at Controller, so everything happens inside a controller method is treated as one transaction. 
However in dropwizard, we can have transaction at a DAO level by implementing `Transactional<DAOclass>`. But if I use two DAOs in a single resource method, it is treated as two different transactions.

Say I have two DAOs

Dao1.java

```
   public abstract class Dao1 implements Transactional<Dao1>{
    @sqlQuery(//somequery)
    public abstract void insertIntoArticles();
   }
```

Dao2.java

```
   public abstract class Dao2 implements Transactional<Dao2>{
    @sqlQuery(//somequery)
    public abstract void insertIntoArticlesChildren();
   }
```

ArticleResource.java

```
    @POST
    @PATH("/articles")
    public void insertArticleAndItsChildren(Integer articleId){
     try{
       dao1.begin();
       dao2.begin();
       dao1.insertIntoArticles();
       dao2.insertIntoArticlesChildren();
       dao1.commit();
       dao2.commit();   
    }catch(Exception e){
     dao1.rollback();
     dao2.rollback();
    }
}
```

In the above example, dao1 and dao2 have two different transactions. But I need everthing under a single transaction
So is there any way of specifying transactional boundaries at Resource level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jdbi/O5rxzwmlwjM

@CreateSqlObject seems to be the answer.